# Is there a JSpinner like component for a touchscreen?

Tags: java, touchscreen, jspinner

I'd like to use a control similar to JSpinner but i need to use it on touchscreen.

JSpinner arrow are too small.

I'm looking in google but i can't find anything!

Do you know some component i can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Swing components following [this](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html) guide. That way you can specify the size of the knobs and whatnot.